# Displaying fetched html information, inside radio streaming app with Android App-inventor

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, app-inventor

Hello I am building my first App, It's function is to listen to my internet music stream and to play the information about the song what is current playing.

I managed to get the music playing and retrieve data from my html page, which holds the song info. However it displays the raw text instead of the widget.

So my question is, how do i get the html displayed properly and that it also updates every 20 seconds?? Like it does on the actual html page? (http://baasdata.net)

I included an image with my app inventor coding below:
Seems I am not allowed yet to include an image, because I need to have 10 points. Since it is about a visual programming language only txt is not helping, so please have a look at the code here: http://baasdata.net/appinventor.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `Web.Get` block you get the source code of a web page back, now you can parse that result for the info you want. You can use a custom parse procedure for that, see this example

[image]

That procedure you also can find [here](http://puravidaapps.com/info.php#parse).

To get an update every 20 seconds, just use a `Clock` component and call your web page every 20 seconds to get the updated info again.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer, I will try this. My attempt was fetching the html output and put that as a label above the player controls.